# Angular 2 md-radio-button set value programatically

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to set a value programatically of a `md-radio-button` inside of a `md-radio-group`. Here is my code simplified :

```
<md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioGroupValue">
    <div *ngFor="let answer of answers; let i = index">
       <md-checkbox *ngIf="isMultiple" [(ngModel)]="answer.isCorrect" [value]="i" ngDefaultControl></md-checkbox>
       <md-radio-button *ngIf="!isMultiple" [(ngModel)]="answer.isCorrect" [value]="i" ngDefaultControl></md-radio-button>
       {{ answer.text }}
    </div>
</md-radio-group>
```

When I change `isMultiple` from `true` to `false`, I update `radioGroupValue` too. The first time, there is no md-radio-button checked, and if I change `isMultiple` to `true` again and `false`, the right radiobutton is checked. How can I handle that ?

Comment: Looks like you spelt `*ngIf` as `*nfIf`!

Comment: Yes my bad, I didn't put all my code to be cleaner, so I made a little mistake here ^^, but there is no syntax issue in my component (at least I didn't have an error on console)

Comment: Is it allowed to have `md-checkbox` inside `md-radio-group`?

Comment: Why not ? You can place what you want anywhere, it's just doing nothing on the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check a `md-radio-group` we need to use `[checked]="boolean"` on the html template

```
<md-input-container [checked]="answer.isCorrect"> {{ answer.text }}</md-radio-button>
```